# Controlling legend labels for a plot with color and linetype aesthetic attributes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot four lines with the legend label **AND** color dictated by unique values in the column, "Color_Group" and the linetype by "Line_Type_Group".  Here is code needed to make the data frame, and the data frame itself.

```
data <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                "y"=1:8,
                "Color_Group"=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                "Line_Type_Group"=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1),
                "Group"=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","B2","B2","C1","C1"),
                stringsAsFactors=F)

> data
  x y Color_Group Line_Type_Group  Group
  1 1           A               1     A1
  2 2           A               1     A1
  1 3           A               2     A2
  2 4           A               2     A2
  1 5           B               2     B2
  2 6           B               2     B2
  1 7           C               1     C1
  2 8           C               1     C1
```

The main "Group" column is the result of pasting the color and linetype columns together, and it represents the id for each line.  In order to get one legend, I initially map the color and linetype attributes to this "Group" column.  Below is what I want the plot to look like.

**Desired Plot**
[image]

**Attempt**

For simplicity's sake, I'm recreating the data frame to include columns with the literal color and linetype values.

```
data <- data.frame("x"=c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2),
                "y"=1:8,"Color_Group"=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                "Color"=c(rep("red",4),"blue","blue","green","green"),
                "Line_Type_Group"=c(1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1),
                "Line_Type"=c("solid","solid","dashed","dashed","dashed","dashed","solid","solid"),
                "Group"=c("A1","A1","A2","A2","B2","B2","C1","C1"),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

> data
  x y Color_Group Color Line_Type_Group Line_Type Group
  1 1           A   red               1     solid    A1
  2 2           A   red               1     solid    A1
  1 3           A   red               2    dashed    A2
  2 4           A   red               2    dashed    A2
  1 5           B  blue               2    dashed    B2
  2 6           B  blue               2    dashed    B2
  1 7           C green               1     solid    C1
  2 8           C green               1     solid    C1  


line_type_group <- data$Line_Type
color_group <- data$Color
names(line_type_group) <- data$Group
names(color_group) <- data$Group
labels <- data$Color_Group
names(labels) <- data$Group
#Both attempts at setting labels variable yields plot below
#labels <- c("A","A","B","C")

g <- ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=Group,linetype=Group))+geom_line()
g + scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",values=color_group,labels=labels) +
    scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend",values =line_type_group,labels=labels)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could work around this by suppressing the linetype legend after changing the `values` to what you want and then "manually" setting the linetypes in the `colour` legend using `override.aes`.

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=x, y=y, colour=Group, linetype=Group))+
    geom_line() + 
    scale_colour_manual(values = color_group, labels = labels) +
    scale_linetype_manual(values = line_type_group, guide = "none") +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype = c(1, 2, 2, 1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this give you almost what you want

```
g <- ggplot(data,aes(x=x,y=y,colour=Group,linetype=Group))+geom_line()
g + scale_colour_manual(name="Legend",values=c("red", "red", "blue", "green"), labels = c("A1", "A2", "B", "C")) +scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend",values=c("solid", "dashed", "dashed", "solid"), labels = c("A1", "A2", "B", "C"))
#
g
```

[image]

Comment: Ya I was able to create a similar plot simply by leaving out the labels parameter in the scale functions.  The tricky part is getting ggplot to recognize A1 and A2 as two groups when it comes to defining the line type and one group when defining the color and label name.